# grep RNA parenthesis representation with R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am seeking to extract every time an open parenthesis + any number of dots + close parenthesis happens within my string.

The following is my R code:

```
pos_test <- "..((((............))))))))))....((........))(((....)))..."

pos_test_matrix <- unlist(strsplit(pos_test, ""))

grep(pos_test_matrix, pattern = "[(]+[.]+[)]")
```

Please advise, the grep returns `integer(0)`

What I'd like is the following:

[image: Output from http://regexr.com/]

Comment: `gregexpr("\\(\\.*\\)", post_test)`?

Comment: I added a screenshot to explain the output I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Using the `stringr` package:

```
x <- "..((((............))))))))))....((........))(((....)))..."

library(stringr)

str_extract_all(x, "\\(+\\.*\\)+")
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "((((............))))))))))"    "((........))"     "(((....)))"
> ```

Or in base R:

```
mx = gregexpr("\\(+\\.*\\)+", x)

sapply(1:length(mx[[1]]), function(i) {

  substr(x, mx[[1]][i], mx[[1]][i] + attr(mx[[1]], "match.length")[i] - 1)

})
```

> ```
> [1] "((((............))))))))))"    "((........))"     "(((....)))"
> ```